# How to merge two images in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimage, cgimage, cgimageref

My app requires to merge 2 images. Please guide me on how to stich the images. The common part should be overwritten. While using openCV framework, merging two image's with the help of `cvWarpPerspective(mImage1, warpImage, &HH)` I got only the matching part of the images.

Comment: You should provide a bit more then "merge 2 images". How do you want to merge them? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Go through core image filter refrence

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346

Comment: @basvk actually I am implementing panaroma App, and I wanted to stich 12 images taken in 360 degree direction.

Comment: Be aware of the iPhone dimension limits for images. If you resulting image is too large this will crash your device. I would suggest you read up about CATiledLayer.